# Type error (intermediate value) is not iterable. Error in get method with Express parameters

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios

I'm trying to make a query with the MySQL WHERE clause using the get method with Express parameters:

```
app.get('/getuserverify/:email', async (req, res) => {
  const {email} = req.params;

  try{
const [rows] = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?;", [email]);
    if (rows.length === 0) {
      res.json({ disponivel: true });
    } else {
      res.json({ disponivel: false });
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

On the front-end I'm using the Axios get method:

```
const emailVerify = async (email) => {
        try {
            setMsg("Aguarde"); //Feedback
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5080/getuserverify/${email}`);
            if (response.data.disponivel) {
                setMsg(""); //Feedback
                return true;
            } else {
                setMsg(""); //Feedback
                return false;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setMsg(""); //Feedback
            console.error('Erro ao verificar a disponibilidade do email:', error);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

But the code throws the following error:
**TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable.**
(In the email parameter in the query in Express).

I'm developing a React Native application. This part is used to check whether the email entered in the registration form already exists.

I tried changing the way to get the parameter in "req.params", but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Where exactly it throws the error? can you post full error message?

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
    at C:\Users\Yohan\Documents\SysmoCode\SysmoCode\src\db\ba
ckDB.js:23:20
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/proce
ss/task_queues:95:5).



It points to the line of code where the array that serves as content for the query in MySQL is located:
"const [rows] = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?;", [email]);"

Comment: What database library are you using? It looks like the response of your database query is not returning an array, so when you try to access the first element of the array with `const [rows]` it is giving you the above error